# How to make an unit test always pass?

Tags: java, testing, reflection

Let's assume someone has to write a solution to a problem and I have to test his solution with some tests. Is it possible (maybe with reflections or something) his program to pass all my tests, but to have nothing in common with the real solution to the problem?

Comment: It had to happen. Instead of a student more or less cheating on homework by asking this site, here it looks like we might have a teaching assistant looking for a shortcut to actually reading student code. (please don't take offense, @brain_damage.)

Comment: @bmargulies, I know my CS program at least often requires TAs to use an automated grader.  So while brain_damage may be a grader, that doesn't mean he's "cheating."  He could just be curious.

Comment: @Matt I avoided the word 'cheat' for that reason.

Comment: @brain_damage, if a student manages to write code that passes all your tests without having anything to do with the real problem, then you should definitely give him/her an A :) heheh

Comment: @Lirik, really?  If I learn that your test expects T,F,F,T, and I just write a println to put out T,F,F,T, do I really deserve an A?

Comment: @Lirik, maybe this student deserves A, but not in designing algorithms, but in knowing how to use Java :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General Case**

In the general case, no.  Since they do not even know you implemented the test correctly, nothing they do - not even correctly implementing the homework - can guarantee passing the test.

**Special Cases**

If the students can run your test, they could use a learning algorithm.

If the students have access to the source code of your test, they can look for tricks like using reflection to get expected results stored in variables.  If they can't find any source code tricks, they can still compile and run your tests.

If the students have access to the byte code of your test, they can probably disassemble it and use source code tricks.  Even if you effectively obsfuscated it, they can still run it.

If the students know that you are testing student code against other student code, all they have to do is be consistent.

**Recommendations**

1. Do not make the test available to students.  They should be independently testing their homework.  After they have submitted their homework to you for formal evaluation, run the tests.
2. Use randomization to make your tests more robust.
3. If your test compares student code against other student code, then you should manually investigate every failure.  Maybe one student implemented correctly and the others copied an incorrect implementation.  In this case, majority rules rewards incompetence.
4. You may collect their tests and test their tests.

Comment: This is a good answer. In programming competitions such as the ACM-ICPC, the competitors are given one or two test cases, but entirely different test cases are used to test the code, ones not disclosed to the students. If the student is given all the test cases, then they can of course return what you want to see for the input without writing the actual algorithms for it, but with reasonable measures taken, this can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Even without the source code to the tests, they could use a byte-code manipulator like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or a decompiler to correlate the inputs and the desired response.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4 has `@Ignore` annotation, which is used in this way:

```
@Ignore
@Test
public void testSmth() {
   ...
}
```

But I'm trying to imaging the situation you've described. And the only thing I can thing about is something like ACM problems verifier (like [PC^2](http://www.ecs.csus.edu/pc2/)).

And if it's the case, you'll call the code for testing and you'll have full control on the flow. So users wouln't have possibility to cheat in this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely**.

If the students discover what your tests are looking for, they can write code which produces that result, without solving the homework problem.

And reflection?  Yes, if you keep your expected results in variables.  I'm not sure if it's possible to read inline constants.   But regardless, run their code in a sandbox with a security manager.  You want to do that anyway: what if their code is malicious, or has unintended consequences?

Comment: Or they allocate a ton of pointers and don't free them because they're not very good programmers...